Manhua- MC receiving a message within the game he was playing and he had a time limit before entering the game world, he prepared himself to do it
The story begins with our protagonist receiving a message within the game he was playing and he had a time limit before entering the game world, he prepared himself by purchasing military items and supplies. When entering the game he found himself in an apocalypse, then later he discovers that he has a time limit to be in that apocalypse and return to reality, in the first chapters he comes across a blonde woman who is trying to survive monsters or bandits and the protagonist will save her. After saving her, he discovers that he has an aiming ability and a system, he asks the woman to get jewelry and gold for when he returns to bring supplies.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

You could improve this Anime Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.
